# When an answerer edits their previous answer to readdress the problem, should I get a notification?

Tags: support, answers, edits, notifications

Basically, I didn't know someone had fully answered my question because they edited their previous answer.

Not major by any means...

- I posted a question.
- A poster answered by pointing out a bug.
- I corrected the bug and updated question with how problem was closer to being solved, but still not solved.
- The poster edited his response with new information that answered my question correctly.
- I did not know the edit had happened, as I would have if another poster has separately posted another answer (i.e. I would have gotten an alert).

Answer (score 1):

I would expect one would be notified, but I'm afraid this currently is not the case. For notifications on favorites, [the following applies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84374/how-to-access-all-of-my-favorites/84387#84387):

> [...] by changes I mean, new answers were added, or new comments on the question. As if you owned the question you favorited.

So, *for favorite questions*, edits on answers do *not* give one a notification. And given the last sentence of the above quote, I'd say the same applies to edits on answers to one's own questions. And currently that seems to be by design.