# How to access ALL of my favorites?

Tags: support, user-interface, bookmarks

OK, I know where I can find the list of favorites. I know how to sort them using the "added", "recent", ... buttons.

But in the list I have, there are only 9 favorites, but I have about 30 bookmarked. So I am missing some button to access the next page, or am I just to ... to see it? What am i missing?

I am using the latest Opera, but I tried also Firefox.

When I think about it, I am not sure if I did realy 30 clicks on bookmarks, I know that I bookmarked some and the 31 I get from the information when I am moving the mouse on my user name.

[image]

Comment: The 31 you see there represents changes to favorites. So, you might have only 9 favorite questions, but these have been edited 31 times during the last month.

Comment: As an aside, for the screenshot: [I LOVE JPEG!! JPEG! JPEG!](http://lbrandy.com/blog/2008/10/my-first-and-last-webcomic/) ;-)

Comment: @alex, or [have been commented on](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange#comments-59445).

Comment: I think I am going to understand, I assumed that are changes done by me, but it makes sense to inform about changes done on the questions. Is there an indicator, which bookmark has changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those numbers represent *changed* favorites in the specified time period.

(edit: by changes I mean, new answers were added, or new comments on the question. As if you owned the question you favorited.)

They do not represent total favorites.

Comment: can you confirm that, by design, this includes new comments, but excludes edits to answers? (See [Notify question OP (and those who marked it a favourite) if an answer has been modified](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64692/notify-question-op-and-those-who-marked-it-a-favourite-if-an-answer-has-been-mo) and the comments at [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange#comments-59445) to trigger notifications.)

Comment: @arjan see my edit

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification, so it's comments on the _question_ only. I've always wondered ... "As if you owned the question" says everything.

Comment: Jeff noted [elsewhere](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129232/are-bounty-placers-notified-of-comments/129236#comment353626_129236): *"that favorites functionality has been broken for over a year now; it does not behave that way and hasn't for 12+ months. We haven't figured out what to replace it with."* (I guess the "12+ months" is a bit off, as the above post is just 13 months old.)

Answer (score 3):

We only see 10 favorites ever by your account, and 1 of those was unfavorited, so the 9 displaying should be correct.  Can you provide an example of a question you favorited that isn't showing up?

Comment: @Arjan - "my English is failing me"....no no, mine is :)

Comment: @Nick OK maybe the problem is a different one, I added a picture to the description.

Comment: @Arjan: Thanks for the confirmation, that's somehow what I expected. Now I'd like to know what counts as a "change" ... comments, too?

Comment: Given [Notify question OP (and those who marked it a favourite) if an answer has been modified](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64692/notify-question-op-and-those-who-marked-it-a-favourite-if-an-answer-has-been-mo), edits to answers do NOT trigger the notification, but comments indeed do. (Hence the many comments at [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange), @Hendrik.)

Comment: @Arjan: I'm just not sure if this is still valid with the new drop-down menu. But I see that you already asked Jeff about this. Thanks!

Comment: @Hendrik - no...this is a totally different question from when I answered, the misunderstanding is explained in Jeff's answer.

Answer (score 0):

To see the "clean" list of your favorites click your user name to reach your profile page, in there you'll see tabs "Info" (active by default), "reputation", "activity", "responses" and "favorites". Click that last tab to see all your favorites in clean design, sorted by the date they were added.

Direct link to this list: https://stackoverflow.com/users/626273/stema?tab=favorites

The whole box that appear on hovering your user name is meant for seeing **changes** as explained already by others. :)