# Allow @ replies to bounty poster on questions

Tags: feature-request, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are bounty placers notified of comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129232/are-bounty-placers-notified-of-comments)

Currently there is no way to ping the poster of a bounty. Could we have the ability to @reply the poster of a bounty so we can inquire further about the nature of a bounty? And/Or respond to the text presented under the bounty request?

Comment: And while at it: also the approvers of suggested edits? (So we can give them feedback about [bad](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141089/if-it-is-in-italic-it-must-be-pretty) [approvals](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132732/auto-rollback-any-edits-made-by-a-spammer-when-his-account-get-nuked).)

Comment: Already done, see [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129232/are-bounty-placers-notified-of-comments) and its answers.  Note that the list of who can be notified via `@whoever` and which names will be autocompleted after typing `@<character(s)>` are not identical.

Comment: @blahdiblah ah, so it does notify it just doesn't autocomplete. Cool thanks.