# Post a comment to the person who offered the bounty

Tags: feature-request

I've run into the following scenario on Stack Overflow several times now:

1. Person 1 asks a question that is unanswered, and remains unanswered or has an "unsatisfactory" or out of date answer.
2. Person 2 offers a bounty on Person 1's question. Person 2's bounty comment is unclear. By "bounty comment" I am referring to the bit of text that appears under the bounty notice.

It seems that offering a bounty on a question does not count as "participation" in the question. Of course this assumes that Person 2 has not otherwise commented/ posted on the question.

In the above scenario, there is no way to post a comment and direct it at the person who offered the bounty (Person 2). In other words, if I click in the comment box under the question and type "@Person", then there is no "@Person2" popup - this to me means that I cannot ask Person 2 for clarification on the bounty.

I have read the following post and my scenario above does not seem to be covered: [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

**Question: Am I correct that there's no way to ask for clarification from the person who offered the bounty?  If not, can this be added as a feature?**

Here is a sample post on SO where Person 2 has offered a bounty, but has not otherwise participated: [MongoDB/NoSQL: Keeping Document Change History](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507624/mongodb-nosql-keeping-document-change-history)

Note - the above SO post might not be the best example because I originally had a question for the person who offered the bounty, but no longer do. But as I mentioned originally, I've run into other questions where I've wanted to do so.

Comment: Typically you can just post a comment. The person who makes a bounty is _highly_ likely to come back to it frequent.

Comment: Apparently @replies work: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129232/are-bounty-placers-notified-of-comments making this [status-completed] I'd say.

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi - that could work if there are not many comments. However, there is a limit to the number of comments displayed, which means that the new comment is "buried".

Comment: @Bart - so it is a hidden feature. Still, it would be nice if the auto-complete would show the name of the person who offered the bounty.

Comment: @chuex auto-complete is not designed to pick up names unless they are in comments.  @ comments work with the editor of a post as well, but you have to manually type the name

Comment: I can confirm that @Replies do in fact work with bounties that I have not commented on. I've done it here on meta several times, as well as it being done to me.

Comment: @Bart - please add your comment as an answer. I'll accept it.

Comment: @All - thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already can leave such comments, [as was confirmed in this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129232/are-bounty-placers-notified-of-comments). Just use the [standard @reply format](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) to notify the user offering the bounty.

You won't get the username auto-complete option if the username doesn't also appear within the comments. But other than that it should work just fine.