# How to ask or contact bounty creator?

Tags: support, bounties

I have answered some time ago an old question [How to run maven from java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141788/how-to-run-maven-from-java)

And now someone added bounty to this question with comment:

> Current answers are not full. Please give exact working examples.

I'm sure, than my answer has fully working example. Can I contact him and ask for more details?

Can I notify him by simply putting @HisName into comment?

Comment: I believe you can @reply to a bounty owner using the comments on the question

Comment: See this question regarding if bounty places are notified of comments: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129232/are-bounty-placers-notified-of-comments?rq=1

Comment: Also please note, though, that while you may feel the question has a fully-working and complete example, it's also valid for others to feel that's not the case, and offer bounties for a more complete example or information.

Comment: Yes, I understand this, there is a reason fot contacting him.